# laravel morph relation access to models data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

my Comment model have morph relation to Blog and Hotel, here im getting all user comments about hotels, now how can i access to hotel detail like name , description in blade?

```
 $hotelComments = Comment::whereHasMorph(
        'commentable',
        Hotel::class,
        )->whereUserId(\Auth::id())->get();
```

blade:

```
     @foreach ($hotelComments as $hc)
        <tr>
            <td class="">{{ $hc->body }}</td>
            <td class="">{{ $hc-> ??? hotel name ??? }}</td>

          </tr>
        @endforeach
```

Blog and Hotel :

```
 public function comments(){
        return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, "commentable");
    }
```

Comment Model:

```
  public function commentable(){
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use belongsto relation on your comments model like this

```php
 public function hotel()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Hotel::class,'commentable_id');
    }
```

In your controller :

```php
public function index(){
   $comments = Comments::where('commentable_type','App\Hotels')->with('hotel')->get();
   foreach($comments as $comment){
      dd($comment->hotel)
   }   
}
```